# Any way to avoid the double "Buy" dialog for non auto renewing subscriptions on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

So 2 years after this question : [You've already purchase this subscription. Tap Buy to renew or extend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181487/youve-already-purchase-this-subscription-tap-buy-to-renew-or-extend-it)

I'm still seeing that when renewing a non auto renewing subscription that the user get's 2 "Buy" dialogs even if the subscription is already expired:

First dialog: **"Confirm your In-App Purchase"**

Second dialog (after clicking Buy on the first one): **"You've Already Purchased This Subscription, Tap Buy to renew or extend it".**

Is there really no way to avoid this? I'm testing in the sandbox right now but no reason to think it is different in production. User can now end up with 3 dialog boxes (1 to enter password for App Store, then the 2 dialogs).

Comment: "...even if the subscription is already expired" for non renewing subscriptions iTunes has no idea how long the subscription lasts for, there is no way for iTunes to know if its expired or not since you don't enter a duration.

Comment: @Robert yeah true (another annoyance, as they could easily manage this) but still stupid for Apple to show 2 dialogs. User confirms once, then confirms again. The developer can easily just not show a purchase option if the subscription is still good. Apple should just show the second dialog.